# Install MudBlazor in Dotnet 8 Blazor Project

Tags: .net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I am starting a side project with blazor and planning to us MudBlazor as UI lib in dotnet 8. My biggest roadblock currently is, When we create new dotnet 8 Blazor project, it creates 2 projects in solution.
I understand one is client project and other is something that will be on server. But what I don't understand is in which project should I install MudBlazor nuget package and configure it's services. Should it be in *.Client project or the one which is in server.
Please help me figure out.

Comment: When you get 2 project's I assume you are using Blazor Webassembly instead of Blazor Server, right ? The UI Framework Nuget Package has to be put where the UI is displayed. That would be the Client side.

Comment: @jeb the new dotnet 8 Blazor WebApp is both servewr and webassembly in 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post, you should install it on the client side.

https://medium.com/@anasyunus/installing-mudblazor-in-a-net-8-blazor-project-cba586e34166

Answer (score 4):

#### Working code example and project

I have created a project with functioning code [here](https://github.com/tysongibby/MudBlazorTemplateApp).

Follow these steps to create a MudBlazor .NET 8 application:

- Create new Blazor Web App Solution with Interactive render mode: `Auto (server and webassembly) , Interactivity location : Global`.
- Install MudBlazor into the client project using the Nuget package manager.
- Add `@using MudBlazor` to the  `_imports.razor` file of both the server and client projects.
- In Server Project `App.razor` file `<head>` element, add the links for the MudBlazor fonts and stylesheets.

```
<head>
  ...
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
  ...
```

- Lower in the `<body>` element of the same file, after `blazor.web.js` `<script>` tag add the `MudBlazor.min.js` `<script>` tag.

```
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

- In both the `Server` and `Client` projects add `builder.Services.AddMudServices();` after `builder` creation.
- In the `Client` layout folder, replace the contents of the file `MainLayout.razor` with the following:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar>
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        My Application
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen">
        <NavMenu/>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Medium">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}
```

- In the `Server` project go to the `program.cs` and locate the lines:

```
app.MapRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
.AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
.AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
```

Update them to reflect the name of your client project like this:

app.MapRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
.AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
.AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(YourBlazorProject.Client._Imports).Assembly);

NOTE: replace "YourBlazorProject.Client" with the name of your client project.

If you want to run a simple test to see if the setup is correct, do the following:

- Go to the `Home.Razor` page in your `Client` project/pages folder. This is the page with @page "/".
- Add the following `MudBlazor` components to the top page

```
<MudMenu Label="Click here to test"> 
<MudMenuItem>It works</MudMenuItem> </MudMenu>
```

- Now run the project. Click on the `MudMenu` "Click here to test". If the menu opens and shows the "It works" it means you have successfully setup `MudBlazor` in `.NET 8` with interactivity.

The steps outlined here are based on a comment made by ATEEKGIT on [MudBlazor GitHub repo](https://github.com/MudBlazor) - [Issue .NET 8 Support #7430](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/7430) - [Comment 7828704](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/7430#discussioncomment-7828704).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there are two open issues related to the MudBlazor and .NET 8 Blazor web assembly.

Due to the changes in the Blazor rendering implementation MudBlazor is not working.

https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7510
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7774

Comment: This is the open issue tracking the situation: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/7430

Comment: See my answer below to get a step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77790762/9538068